# Derivation of $ R_{N(t)}(\tau) $ from its $f_{N(t)}(\eta)$

Tags: noise, autocorrelation, gaussian, proof

How can we prove the auto-correlation function of white gaussian noise $\{ R_{N(t)}(\tau) \}$ is $\frac{N_0}{2} \delta(\tau)$ from its p.d.f in equation below?
$$
f_{N(t)}(\eta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}}\exp\left(\frac{-(\eta-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right)
$$

**My Approach:**

We know: $\frac{N_0}{2}=\sigma^2 \quad(\text{ or variance}) \tag{1}$
We also know: 
$$
R_{X(t)}(\tau)= E[X(t)X(t+ \tau)]=\int_{y=- \infty}^{\infty} \int_{x= - \infty}^{\infty} x \space y \space f_{X(t) X(t+\tau)}(x,y)  \space dx  \space dy
$$
Where $f_{X(t) X(t+\tau)}(x,y) \text{ is joint p.d.f}$
$$\text{so , } R_{N(t)}(\tau)= E[N(t)N(t+ \tau)]=\int_{y=- \infty}^{\infty} \int_{x= - \infty}^{\infty} x \space y \space f_{N(t)N(t+\tau)}(x,y)  \space dx  \space dy$$
Now we know 
$$f_{N(t)}(\eta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}}\exp\left(\frac{-(\eta-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right)$$
then, how can we find $f_{N(t)N(t+\tau)}(x,y)$ ?

Comment: Hint : You can use the definition of a white noise process. That is, all frequency components are present in the power spectral density (PSD)

Comment: yeah I know that process @AnVij ; but i want to derive its auto-correlation function from its p.d.f

Comment: A Gaussian PDF does not imply whiteness, so you can't derive the auto-correlation function just from the PDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @MattL points out in a comment, a Gaussian pdf does not imply whiteness. Indeed, it can be argued that the assumption that the process is a continuous-time white noise process is contrary to the belief that the random variables constituting the process even *have* a pdf of any kind.  *Continuous-time white noise* is a mythical beast that is used to account for the empirical observation that the power spectral density $S_{\scriptstyle{\text{output}}}(f)$ of the noise at the output of a linear filter with transfer function $H(f)$ can be expressed as
$$S_{\scriptstyle{\text{output}}}(f) = \frac{N_0}{2}|H(f)|^2,-\infty < f < \infty,$$
a result that is perfectly consistent with the standard theory of wide-sense-stationary processes in linear systems which claims that 
$$S_{\scriptstyle{\text{output}}(f)} = S_{\scriptstyle{\text{input}}(f)}|H(f)|^2, -\infty < f < \infty,$$
*provided* that we are willing to suspend belief and assume that the *input* noise has power spectral density $\frac{N_0}{2}, -\infty < f < \infty,$ which has infinite power. (This suspension of belief must be accompanied by a most solemn vow to not attempt to solve the world's energy crisis by plugging in the power grid into a white noise generator!). Formally, a continuous-time white noise process is defined to be a continuous-time zero-mean wide-sense stationary process whose power spectral density has constant value for all choices of frequency $f$. Continuous-time white noise can *only* be observed through some kind of device (whether linear or nonlinear) which perforce performs some kind of filtering or bandwidth reduction so that the *observation* has finite variance and the *observed process* has finite power. The *observed process* is **not** called a white noise process.

The inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{N_0}{2}, -\infty < f < \infty,$ is the autocorrelation function $\frac{N_0}{2}\delta(t)$ of the white noise process where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta. It is a shibboleth often murmured on this site that the *value* $\delta(0)$ of the Dirac delta is $\infty$ with the usual consequences for this mispronunciation being administered by the *cognoscenti* of dsp.SE, but the point is that we cannot define any kind of pdf for the random variables constituting a white noise process, and very certainly not the Gaussian pdf that the OP wishes to use.  What *is* true that the noise at the output of the linear filter is *Gaussian* noise meaning that the random variables constituting the output noise process are (zero-mean) Gaussian random variables with variance 
$$\sigma^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty S_{\scriptstyle{\text{output}}(f)}\, \mathrm df = \frac{N_0}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |H(f)|^2\mathrm df.$$
This result is also consistent with the view that the input noise process is white *Gaussian* noise in the sense that it is a standard result in the theory of wide-sense-stationary process that linear filtering of a Gaussian process results in a Gaussian process. But it is not possible to ascribe a *variance*  (not even an infinite variance) to these alleged Gaussian random variables in the input process because for all $x$,
$$\lim_{\sigma\to\infty} \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}{{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}} = 0.$$

> In summary, continuous-time white Gaussian noise is a myth used to provide a rationale for the empirical observation that the noise at the output of a linear filter with transfer function $H(f)$ is a zero-mean wide-sense-stationary (and hence strictly stationary) *Gaussian* random process with power spectral density
>   $$S_{\scriptstyle{\text{output}}}(f) = \frac{N_0}{2}|H(f)|^2,-\infty < f < \infty.$$
>   The *only* assumption about the random variables constituting the wide-sense-stationary *input* white noise process is that they all are zero-mean random Gaussian random variables but we cannot ascribe any variance to them or observe them directly or do anything else with them until we have processed them through *some* device of finite bandwidth.

More than what you probably want to know about continuous-time white Gaussian noise
can be found in the Appendix of [this lecture 
note](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece361/sp2011/Newlectures/Lecture03.pdf)
of mine.

---

In view of a veritable flood of comments from @markleeds on the original version of this answer, it is worth noting that on dsp.SE (and any place else where MATLAB is the *lingua franca*), there is also the concept of a *discrete-time* white noise process.  A discrete-time process is a countable collection of random variables $\{X[k]\colon k \in \mathbb Z\}$ (notice the change from $X(t)$ to $X[k]$: this is very commonly-used notational convention to distinguish the two cases) and a discrete-time *white noise* process is just a collection of zero-mean finite-variance independent identically distributed random variables $N[k]$, $k \in \mathbb Z$. The (discrete-time) autocorrelation function of the process is $$R_N[k] = E[N[m]N[m+k]] = \sigma^2\delta[k]$$ where $\delta[k]$ is the *Kronecker* delta (**not the Dirac delta**) which is defined as
$$\delta[k] = \begin{cases}1, & k=0,\\0, & k\neq 0.\end{cases}$$
Although the same symbol is used in both cases, we use $()$ and $[]$ as clues to tell us what $\delta$ means. Now, what, if any, is the relationship between *samples* of continuous-time white noise and discrete-time white noise? Well, as mentioned above, *sampling* white noise is not a physical reality -- one cannot draw blood from a beast that does not exist! -- and any attempt to do so must take into account the physical properties of the sampler which is a finite-bandwidth device with a switch that closes *for a very short period of time* $\varepsilon$ and then opens again. A simple model for what happens during this time is that what the sampler reads at time $t$ is the value of
$$\int_{t-\varepsilon}^{t}N(\tau)\, \mathrm d\tau$$ which 
is a *random variable*  with mean $0$ and variance 
\begin{align}
\sigma^2 &= E\left[\int_{t-\varepsilon}^{t}N(\tau)\, \mathrm d\tau\int_{t-\varepsilon}^{t}N(\lambda)\, \mathrm d\lambda\right]\\
&= E\left[\int_{t-\varepsilon}^{t}\int_{t-\varepsilon}^{t}N(\tau)N(\lambda)\, \mathrm d\tau \,\mathrm d\lambda\right]\\
&= \int_{t-\varepsilon}^{t}\int_{t-\varepsilon}^{t}E[N(\tau)N(\lambda)]\, \mathrm d\tau \,\mathrm d\lambda\\
&= \int_{t-\varepsilon}^{t}\int_{t-\varepsilon}^{t}\frac{N_0}{2}\delta(\tau-\lambda)]\, \mathrm d\tau \,\mathrm d\lambda\\
&= \int_{t-\varepsilon}^{t}\frac{N_0}{2}\,\mathrm d\lambda\\
&= \frac{N_0}{2}\varepsilon
\end{align}
If $N(t)$ is continuous-time white Gaussian noise with power spectral density $\frac{N_0}{2}$ and the samples are spaced at least $\varepsilon$ apart, say the $k$-th sample is at time $kT$ where $T\geq \varepsilon$, then we have that the $N[k]$ are *independent* zero-mean random variables with variance $\frac{N_0}{2}\varepsilon$, that is, _discrete-time white noise.  If $N(t)$ is a Gaussian process, then the discrete-time process is a Gaussian process in which the random variables are independent $\mathcal N(0,\frac{N_0}{2}\varepsilon$ random variables.

---

Comment: @Dilipe: That was beautiful and educational. I would just add the following: Assuming that brownian motion is viewed as white noise ( don't know if it's definitely viewed that way in DSP )  there is some implied and possible not useful (in DSP) connection between white noise and the gaussian pdf. This is because the three requirements for brownian motion, B_t, are known to be 1) B_t starts at zero so B_0 = 0.  2) stationary independent increments and 3) For every t >0, B_t is normal(0,t). Therefore,  the white noise process, if viewed from its beginning, is a normally distributed process.

Comment: One other thing since I may not have been clear. My point above is that, in the ideal case, where one could sample brownian motion say every 1 second, then  that sampled process could be viewed as N(0,1) in the discrete case. As I said, I  don't know if brownian motion is viewed as white noise in DSP world.

Comment: @markleeds Brownian motion is the _integral_ of white noise from $0$ to $t$, not white noise itself. I don’t know if people in the DSP world view Brownian motion as white noise but if they do, they shouldn’t

Comment: right. it's the integral. but, if you start at $t1$ and then stop at $t2$, then brownian motion over that period is N(0,t2-t1) due to independent increments. So, sampling each observation at 1 second, gives you a normal(0,1) which can be viewed not as an integral and just as a random variable. See Hamilton or Mikosh for how the FCLT can be used to derive brownian motion.

Comment: @Dilipe: It would be useful if you would provide your definition of  white noise. we had a problem with correlation and covariance the other day so possibly something similar here. thanks.

Comment: @Dilipe: See this link if interested. Integrated brownian motion is on page 41 ( variance of the normal  comes to $t^3/3$ because he uses a discrete sum ) and my statement regarding using (t-s) = 1 second as the sampling  time is stated in the proof on the bottom of page 95,  https://people.emich.edu/ocalin/Teaching_files/D18N.pdf

Comment: Dilipe:  My last comment on this but definitely I'll read anything you say.  Assume we define BW as integrated WN. Then, based on page 95 ,  the  BW process over t1 to t2 is normal(0,t2-t1) by independent increments.  Heuristically, ( definitely not mathematically), since this incremental  process kind of represents a "difference", this implies a connection between WN  and the normal, because differencing an integrated process results in the process itself.  Definitely not a mathematical argument ( WN is really the derivative of BW not the difference ) but,f or me, a useful way to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Points to be noted:

- White noise has zero mean. So, $\mu = 0$.
- White noise also means two samples separated in time are uncorrelated.

$R_{X(t)}(\tau) = E[X(t)X(t+\tau)] = E[X(t)]E[X(t+\tau)] = 0$ when $\tau \neq 0$.

On the other hand, when $\tau = 0$ :

$R_{X(t)}(\tau) = E[X^2(t)] = \sigma^2 $ which is the variance of gaussian noise.

However, there's a catch. I couldn't provide an explanation for $\delta(\tau)$- notation for infinite amplitude at $\tau = 0.$

I think this $\delta(\tau)$ function can be accounted to the classical definition of Auto-correlation function where there is an integral over time as well.

There seems to be a relevant discussion [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31894/where-does-the-delta-function-come-from-if-we-derive-autocorrelation-directly).

Comment: This answer is mostly incorrect. The most relevant part is the reference to MattL's answer to a related question at the very end of the answer.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Can you please elaborate what is wrong with the answer?

Comment: @Manideep: If one is allowed to definite  $R_{x((t)}(\tau)$ as the covariance of, $X(t)$ at lag $\tau$,  where $X(t)$ is a brownian motion process, then there is nothing wrong what you said. Your definition is just a different way of expressing independent increments. But, I'm not from DSP world, so I'm not sure if it can be defined that way in DSP. framework.

Comment: @Manideep: I would take the * out of your definition though. That makes it look like convolution.

Comment: @markleeds Thanks for the suggestion. I did as you suggested.